# How to remove namespace prefix leaving namespace value (XSLT)?

Tags: xml, xslt

I know how to remove namespaces at all but what I need to do is only to remove specific namespace prefixes eg transform this file (removing xenc prefixes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
    </xenc:EncryptedKey>
    <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>AAA=</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
```

into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
    </EncryptedKey>
    <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>AAA=</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
```

Can you help me how it could be done using XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly the same solution as from nwellnhof. But make use of default namesepace in stylesheet.
Add: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"  >
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="xenc:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following stylesheet. It contains the identity transform and a template to strip the namespace of `xenc:*` elements. Note that `xenc:*` attributes are not handled.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xenc:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```